# Unmarshaling attributes in nested xml golang

Tags: xml, go

I've been searching everywhere and can't figure out the solution to this.

I'm trying to get an attribute of a nested xml tag from wikipedia, but have so far been unable to get the nested attribute. I'm specifically trying to get `pageid` from the `page` tag.

Here's an example of the xml:

```
<api batchcomplete="">
  <query>
    <pages>
      <page _idx="25039021" pageid="25039021" ns="0" title="Go (programming language)">
        <extract xml:space="preserve">
          stuff about golang
        </extract>
      </page>
    </pages>
  </query>
</api>
```

Here are the structs that I'm using:

```
type Page struct {
    PageID string `xml:"pageid,attr"`
}

type Extract struct {
    Text string `xml:"query>pages>page>extract"`
    Page Page   `xml:"query>pages>page"`
}
```

but still extract.page.pageid comes back with nothing. Anything I'm missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structs should change to this :

```
type Page struct {
    PageID string `xml:"pageid,attr"`
    Text   string `xml:"extract"`
}

type Extract struct {
    Page Page `xml:"query>pages>page"`
}

fmt.Println(extract.Page.PageID)
fmt.Println(extract.Page.Text)
```

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work before, but this way makes more sense and I can get `pageid`. Thanks for the help!